# \multirow in a \multicol

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

i want a table like in the picture but i got a error!

here \multicol{2}{|l|}{\multirow{4}{*}{1&2&3&4}}

## [image: pic]

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}|p{5cm}|  }
\hline
1& 2  \\
\hline
1& 2\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{1}\\
\hline
1&2 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{1}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{
\multirow{4}{*}{1&2&3&4}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Scénario d’exception}\\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{1}\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: As always on this site, please always post full (but minimal) examples others can copy and test as is. We cannot test sniplets like this without adding stuff.

Comment: Additionally, how is your code related to the image? It does not male much sense. What are you trying to do with `\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\multirow{4}{*}{1&2&3&4}}`? You cannot do that. Perhaps you should start over and start by explaining what exactly it is you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `tabularray` and `enumitem` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tblr}%
{
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  itemsep=0.5ex,
                  label=\textbullet,
                  wide,
                  after=\end{minipage},
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                  }
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tblr}{width=100mm,
                 hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {X[l,font=\bfseries] X[j]},
                 hspan=minimal, measure=vbox
                 }
1   &   2   \\
1   &   2   \\
1   &   2   \\
1   &   2   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l} Scénario nominal
    &       \\  
1   &   2   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{j, font=\normalfont}
    \begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1][1-3]
\item \lipsum[1][1-3]
\item \lipsum[1][1-3]
\item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \end{itemize}
    &       \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l} Scénario d’exception
    &       \\
\SetCell[c=2]{j, font=\normalfont}
    \begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1][1-2]
\item \lipsum[1][1-1]
\item \lipsum[1][1-2]
    \end{itemize}
    &       \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Error caused by  \AtBeginEnvironment{tblr}%
{
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  itemsep=0.5ex,
                  label=\textbullet,
                  wide,
                  after=\end{minipage},
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                  }
}

Comment: If you tested MWE as it is, this should not happened. Mentioned code lines works with with any LaTeX installation from last two years (tested). Which version of `tabularray` you have. Proposed solution is tested by 2022A version.

Comment: @YassineRaddaoui, any news?